# Google reports that URLs in news sitemap aren't on a verified news site

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-news

I have a News site with Bengali and English. I have done Google News inclusion and it is getting indexed. But Search Console is showing 2 errors about the sitemap.

[image]

[image]

> Your Sitemap is on a site that is not in the Google News database. Google News can only accept Sitemaps from sites that we crawl. If your site is crawled by Google News, please check that the URL of your Sitemap agrees with the URLs of your articles as they appear on Google News, including any leading "www". If you would like to request inclusion of your site in Google News, please contact the Google News support team.

What am I supposed to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I remember this happened to me in like 2015.

Here is the link that I had to visit in the Google News Publisher Center:

`https://partnerdash.google.com/partnerdash/d/news#p:id=pfehome`

Comment: I think users weren't clear what your link here was for and downvoted it. It's always best to add as much details as you can so it doesn't get flagged as low-quality.  I added some info for you.